# Highlight Combobox when SelectedValue is not in ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have a window with many Comboboxes. These Comboboxes look like this, there is a style:

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxFlat}" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static binding:BindingCollections.Names}}" 
              SelectedValuePath="Key"
              DisplayMemberPath="Value"
              SelectedValue="{Binding NameID}"/>
```

ItemsSource is a key-value-list, the values are displayed. This all works so far.

Now it can happen that the property that binds to SelectedValue contains a key that is not present in the ItemsSource. If this happens, the Combobox should be marked somehow, e.g. Combobox should get a red frame.

What is the best way to do this?
Is it possible to define such a behaviour in the Combobox style?

Comment: This is achievable through trigger but it may not be possible to show the invalid value  in combobox.

Comment: @Sham ok, I see! It is not necessary to show the invalid key in ComboBox, highlighting is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could bind to the `SelectedIndex` property of the `ComboBox` and the `NameID` source property and implement an `IMultiValueConverter` that returns `true` if the `SelectedIndex` property returns `-1` while the `NameID` property returns a value, e.g.:

```
class MultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)values[0] == -1 && values[1] != null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox ... 
          SelectedValue="{Binding NameID}">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <local:MultiConverter x:Key="MultiConverter" />
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource ComboBoxFlat}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="SelectedIndex" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                            <Binding Path="NameID" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="10" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Is this also possible without specifying the property (NameID) expilzit?

Comment: No, of course you need to specify the property to bind to.